# Script to extract highest latency from traceroute

Tags: bash, latency, awk

I'm looking for a script that can extract the line with the highest latency hop from a traceroute. Ideally it would look at the max or avg of the 3 values by line. How can I so that?

This is what I tried so far:

```
     traceroute www.google.com | awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n", $2, $3+$4+$5; }' | sort -rgk2 | head -n1
     traceroute -w10 www.google.com | awk '{printf "%s\t%s\n", $2, ($3+$4+$5)/3; }' | sort -rgk2 | head -n1
```

It seemed a step in the right direction, except some of the values coming back from a traceroute are *, so both the sum and the average provide a wrong value.

**Update**
Got one step further:

```
     traceroute www.cnn.com | awk '{count = 0;sum = 0;for (i=3; i<6; i++){ if ($i != "*") {sum += $i;count++;}}; printf "%s\t%s\t%s\t%s\n", $2, count, sum, sum/count }' | sort -rgk2
```

now need to intercept if I dont' have a column 4,5. Sometimes traceroute only provides 3 stars like this:

```
     17   207.88.13.153  235.649ms  234.864ms  239.316ms 
     18   *  *  *
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try:

```
$ traceroute 8.8.8.8 | awk ' BEGIN { FPAT="[0-9]+\\.[0-9]{3} ms" }
                           /[\\* ]{3}/ {next}
                           NR>1  {
                                   for (i=1;i<4;i++) {gsub("*","5000.00 ms",$i)}
                                   av = (gensub(" ms","",1,$1) + gensub(" ms","",1,$2) + gensub(" ms","",1,$3))/3
                                   if (av > worst) {
                                     ln = $0
                                     worst = av
                                   }
                                 }
                           ND { print "Highest:", ln, " Average:", worst, "ms"}'
```

which gives:

```
Highest:  6  72.14.242.166 (72.14.242.166)  7.383 ms 72.14.232.134 (72.14.232.134)  7.865 ms  7.768 ms  Average: 7.672  ms
```

If there are three asterix (asteri?) `* * *` the script assumes that the hop isn't responding with the IGMP response and ignores it completely.  If there are one or two `*` in a line, it gives them the value of 5.0 seconds.

Comment: Hmm - you divide through 3 in all cases so if I have 110.666ms * 159.334ms I would get 90ms which wouldn't be the accurate average of 135ms

Comment: I think the problem is the lack of a definition for `*`.  In your comment, you chose to ignore it and divide by two. It could also be defined as 5.0 seconds as this is the time at which traceroute gives up and shows the asterix.  It could also be defined as infinity as no reponse has been seen. In the latter case you could end up with more than one line as the worst case response.

Comment: True. * isn't defined. It appears when the request times out. Typically that happens when a server is configured to ignore traceroute. I checked with 30 sec timeouts and still got *. So I concluded ignoring is as good as assuming a value (where the timeout - default 3sec - would be appropriate) Awk turns it into zero anyway. But having 2 values and dividing by 3 doesn't yield a usable result.

Comment: I've edited it (previously) so that if there are three `*` then it assumes the server is ignoring the request.  However, if there are one or two `*` and a response, then the server isn't ignoring the request, but is taking a very long time to respond (> 5 sec by default).

Comment: Thx a lot appreciate your persistence to help me out here!

Answer (score 5):

You will have to

- Kick off a traceroute
- Collect each line of output ( a pipe would likely work well here)
- Use a tool like [awk](http://linux.die.net/man/1/awk) to

  - Analyze the line and extract the information you want
  - Compare the values you just got with previous values and store the current line if appropriate
  - At the end of the input print the stored value

Comment: @stwissel got some $$$ to pass to me ? We generally don't write scripts and do people's jobs for them but we're happy to point you in the right direction or even debug stuff if you show us your workings.

Comment: Pecked the original question on glass, now added the attempts I made so far. For a "clean" traceroute I have a solution, but need a step when * comes back

Answer (score 1):

Stephan, you could try and use pchar a derivative of pathchar. It should be in the Ubuntu repository.

I takes a while to run though so you need some patience. It will show you throughput and that will be much better than latency for determining the bottleneck.

http://www.caida.org/tools/taxonomy/perftaxonomy.xml

Here is an example:

```
rayd@raydHPEliteBook8440p ~ sudo pchar anddroiddevs.com
pchar to anddroiddevs.com (31.221.38.104) using UDP/IPv4
Using raw socket input
Packet size increments from 32 to 1500 by 32
46 test(s) per repetition
32 repetition(s) per hop
 0: 192.168.0.20 (raydHPEliteBook8440p.local)
    Partial loss:      0 / 1472 (0%)
    Partial char:      rtt = 6.553065 ms, (b = 0.000913 ms/B), r2 = 0.241811
                       stddev rtt = 0.196989, stddev b = 0.000244
    Partial queueing:  avg = 0.012648 ms (13848 bytes)
    Hop char:          rtt = 6.553065 ms, bw = 8759.575088 Kbps
    Hop queueing:      avg = 0.012648 ms (13848 bytes)
 1: 80.5.69.1 (cpc2-glfd6-2-0-gw.6-2.cable.virginm.net)
```

Answer (score 0):

Use `mtr --raw -c 1 google.com`. It's wayy faster and easier to parse.